# Exact height of a HTML div given the heights of its child elements

Tags: html, css

If the height of the parent `div` is set to `100%` (as is the case presently) and if I reduce the screen height so that, for example, the last two child elements can't be seen, then the `div` is scrollable.
Now, I don't want all that big red area after the child elements.
So, I am trying to find the exact height of the child elements so that I can set the `height` property of the parent element accordingly.

If I set this height to `calc(5 * 1.2rem + 5 * 0.8em)`, not only I end up with a thin read area that I would expect not to see if my calculation was adequate but also, the `div` is not scrollable at a small height screen size.

I would like the `div` to be scrollable at small height screen sizes.
And when the screen height is large, I don't want that red area.

```css
.css_styles_1
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  background-color: red; 
  line-height: 1rem; 
  /*height: calc(5 * 1.2rem + 5 * 0.8em);*/
  height: 100%;
}
.css_styles_2
{
  font-size: 1.2rem; 
  padding-top: 0.4em; 
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;             
}
.css_styles_2_odd
{
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.css_styles_2_even
{
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_styles_1">
  <div class="css_styles_2 css_styles_2_odd">Text 1</div>
  <div class="css_styles_2 css_styles_2_even">Text 2</div>
  <div class="css_styles_2 css_styles_2_odd">Text 3</div>
  <div class="css_styles_2 css_styles_2_even">Text 4</div>
  <div class="css_styles_2 css_styles_2_odd">Text 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the result to look like?

Comment: just don't give it a fixed height and it should be able to fit all of it children in it, automatically. Anyway, please consider explaining more your desired end result.

Comment: _"In the end, there is a thin red area which belongs to the parent div. Why is that?"_ - because the height value you calculated there based on magic numbers only you know the origin of, apparently is not correct ...? _"Maybe this is not the right approach?"_ - couldn't tell you, because so far I can not even understand what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: "If I set no height, the div contents won't be scrollable in case the screen height is less [...]" -> this may be a problem about how you set the CSS of the parent element of `css_styles_1`. With no specified height it should take the height of its content and that should not cause the scroll problem you describe

Comment: Hi. Ok. Sorry. I changed the code a little bit and tried to reformulate my problem more correctly.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why you are talking about magic numbers. 1.2rem and 0.4em are not magic numbers or are they?

Comment: Ok. What I am describing cannot be seen with that `stackoverflow` snippet. In `codepen` or `vs code`, it can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `height` property, try using `max-height: 100%`.
This will take the total size of the children as long as they do not exceed the total screen size.